# two textures(canvas) for one material to plane

Tags: three.js

How to apply two textures to a single material?
There are two equal sized canvas.
Need to first texture is the default, and the second from the top, but smaller and using offset.

Example on the [photo](https://vk.com/photo111944480_336138372)

Sorry for my english))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use 2 different 3d planes with a texture each.